# Using the half/double angle formulas to solve an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am completely stumped by this problem: $$\cos\theta - \sin\theta =\sqrt{2} \sin\frac{\theta}{2} $$

I know that I should start by isolating $\sin\dfrac{\theta}{2}$

and end up with $$\frac {\cos\theta - \sin\theta}{\sqrt{2}} = \sin\frac{\theta}{ 2}$$

From here on out, I have no idea what steps to take.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use half/double angle formulas?

Answer (score 5):

W/O using the half/double angle formulas,

we have  $$\sin\frac\theta2=\sin\left(\frac\pi4-\theta\right)$$

$$\implies\frac\theta2=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(\frac\pi4-\theta\right)$$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: This solution uses the formula $$b\cos\theta - a\sin\theta = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\sin(\varphi - \theta)$$ where \begin{align*} \cos\varphi & = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\\ \sin\varphi & = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\end{align*}  with $a = 1$ and $b = 1$, from which you can determine that $\varphi = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: What formula is that?

Comment: Use the difference of angles formula $$\sin(\varphi - \theta) = \sin\varphi\cos\theta - \cos\varphi\sin\theta$$ then make the indicated substitutions for $\cos\varphi$ and $\sin\varphi$ to prove it.  Similarly, you can use the sum of angles formula $$\sin(\theta + \varphi) = \sin\theta\cos\varphi + \cos\theta\sin\varphi$$ to show that $$a\sin\theta + b\cos\theta = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\sin(\theta + \varphi)$$ where $\cos\varphi$ and $\sin\varphi$ are defined as above.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, Squaring either sides &  using $\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A$ is another option which needs the elimination of extraneous roots

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos \theta . \sin \frac{\pi}{4} - \cos \frac{\pi}{4} . \sin \theta = \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$$
$$\sin (\frac{\pi}{4} - \theta) = \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4} - \theta = n\pi + (-1)^n(\frac{\theta}{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

Given : $\dfrac{\cos\theta - \sin\theta}{\sqrt{2}} = \sin\dfrac{\theta}{ 2}$

using $\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{2}}$ and squaring both sides,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)-2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{2} & = \frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{2}\\
1-2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) & = 1-\cos(\theta) && \text{because $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta) = 1$}\\
-2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) & = -\cos(\theta)\\
-\sin(\theta) & = -\frac{1}{2}\\
\sin(\theta) & = \frac{1}{2} = \sin(\frac{\pi}{3})
\end{align*}

General Solutions $\theta$ = $n\pi +(-1)^{n}\frac{\pi}{3}$ , $n\in Z$

Comment: When you square $$\frac{\cos\theta - \sin\theta}{\sqrt{2}}$$ you should obtain $$\frac{\cos^2 - 2\cos\theta\sin\theta + \sin^2\theta}{2}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig my fault.... i missed the negative sign

Comment: @N.F.Taussig now i've fixed it

Comment: @DheerajKumar I like your idea.  However, there are other solutions.

Comment: there are infinite solutions I just wrote general one

Comment: @DheerajKumar Once you obtain $$2\sin\theta\cos\theta = \cos\theta$$ you should obtain $$\cos\theta(2\sin\theta - 1) = 0$$  Hence, $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$ is a particular solution.  A general solution explains how to find all the solutions to the problem.